# how do you do a confirm delete modal in Alpine.js

Tags: laravel-livewire, alpine.js

I have a table (using [laravel-livewire-tables](https://github.com/kdion4891/laravel-livewire-tables)) and a custom view which has an edit icon and a delete icon. I am trying to add an alpine.js modal to allow user to confirm delete but I can't figure out where to put the modal code.

If I put it in the custom view, it blows up the tables styling and jams 8 or 9 columns in 1/3 of the screen even when the modal isn't showing.

Anyone have a fiddle or a resource???

Comment: show some codes. as Laravel-Livewire is completely new thing. questions and issues regarding this is hard to understand if you do not explain it properly. However you do explained it correctly but it would be more understandable if you show some codes

Answer (score 1):

confirm.blade.php

```php
<span x-data="{{ $xdata }}" x-cloak>
    <button type="button" x-on:click="isOpen = !isOpen"
        class="inline-flex items-center {{ $classes ?? '' }}
        {{ isset($type) ? 'px-6 py-2 rounded-lg text-white bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-600' : 'text-red-600 hover:text-red-700'}}">
        {{ $link }}
    </button>

    <div style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)" class="fixed z-40 top-0 right-0 left-0 bottom-0 h-full w-full"
        x-show="isOpen" x-on:click.away="isOpen = false" x-transition:enter="ease-out transition-slow"
        x-transition:enter-start="opacity-0" x-transition:enter-end="opacity-100"
        x-transition:leave="ease-in transition-slow" x-transition:leave-start="opacity-100"
        x-transition:leave-end="opacity-0">
        <div class="p-4 max-w-xl mx-auto absolute left-0 right-0 overflow-hidden mt-24">
            <form method="POST" action="{{ $route }}"
                onsubmit="deleteButton.disabled = true; deleteButton.classList.add('base-spinner');">
                @component('components.card', [
                'withFooter' => true
                ])

                <input type="hidden" name="{{ $idName }}" value="{{ $id }}">

                @method('DELETE')
                @csrf

                @component('components.heading', [
                'size' => 'large'
                ])
                {{ $title ?? ''}}
                @endcomponent

                {{ $slot }}

                @slot('footer')
                <div class="text-right">
                    <button type="button" x-on:click="isOpen = false"
                        class="px-4 py-2 rounded-lg text-gray-600 bg-white hover:text-blue-600 shadow mr-2">Cancel</button>
                    <button type="submit" name="deleteButton"
                        class="px-4 py-2 rounded-lg text-white bg-red-500 hover:bg-red-600 shadow">Confirm</button>
                </div>
                @endslot
                @endcomponent
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</span>
```

then in your table td layout

```
<table>
....

<td>
@confirm([
    'classes' => 'ml-1 mr-4',
    'title' => 'Are your sure you want to delete?',
    'link' => 'Delete',
    'id' => $category->id,
    'idName' => 'category_id',
    'route' => route('categories.delete'),
    'xdata' => json_encode([
        'isOpen' => false
    ])
])
    <p>If you delete the record you can't recover it.</p>
    <div class="border rounded-lg mt-4">
        <div class="flex py-2 px-4">
            <div class="mr-2">Category Name:</div>
            <div class="flex-1 text-truncate">
                <p class="mb-0 text-gray-800">{{ $category->name }}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endconfirm
</td>

</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

I use browser windows confirm method.
Using Alpine 3 + Livewire 2.

```
<button @click=" confirm('Are you sure?') ? @this.destoryUser({{$user->id}}) : false" class="text-white bg-gray-500 bg-opacity-30 rounded-full flex items-center justify-center">
```

Using the x-on:click or @click from Alpine then use @this directive to access the Livewire method `destoryUser` function is inside Livewire.

Answer (score 0):

Put your modal form in the livewire parent component.

But since javascript is javascript no matter what framework you use. Whether it's alpinejs, jquery, bootstrap.. etc. at the end of the day, the core language is still javascript.
So my point is, to make it easier for you. Just use the plain old modal bootstrap for the delete pop up and just use the event

you can run a function from the backend with your frontend like this

```
<script>
    Livewire.emit('theEventListenerFromYourBackendCode')
</script>
```

or you can trigger a javascript code using your backend code like this

```
function theEventListenerFunction {
    $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('name-updated', ['newName' => $value]);
}
... // on your frontend
<script>
window.addEventListener('name-updated', event => {
    alert('Name updated to: ' + event.detail.newName);
})
</script>
```

Alternatively, there's a youtube series I found that uses bootstrap modal for the CRUD operations.. you should check it out >>>> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_DQi8TyA9hI